# chrome storage sync, cleared on extension update?

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am struggling to figure out whether data stored in the chrome.storage.sync, will get wiped out when ever I publish a new version of my extension through the chrome developer dashboard.

When users of my extension gets an update (automatically), does this wipe their chrome.storage.sync? I wasn't successful in testing this.

I am asking this because i'm developing a chrome note pad which syncs all the notes through chrome.storage.sync. I wouldn't want my users to lose their notes when i update the extension.

The extension can be found here :
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chromepad/dpofibmpjiejdbmpkflaedamfkglbdfl

Comment: Evidently there's something wrong in your code or it's a bug in the browser. Without the relevant code in the question, this is not answerable, unfortunately.

Comment: No, the data in chrome.storage.sync is not wiped out when the extension is updated.

Comment: @wOxxOm i am referring to chrome.storage.sync.set({}, function(){}) That is the code: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage

Comment: @IvánNokonoko can you confirm from your own experience?

Comment: The relevant code should be included in the question itself. To reiterate my point, there's probably something else in your code that clears the storage, for example, due to incorrect handling of onInstalled event, which is fired on update too. Because the only other explanation is a bug in the browser that affects just you for an unknown reason.

Comment: @wOxxOm The OP didn't say the data was deleted. They just asked if it is so before publishing an update. Eric Xiao: I can confirm from my own experience that the data is not deleted when the extension is updated.

Comment: @wOxxOm yes sorry, i should have indicated in the question that there are no background scripts for my extension.

Comment: @IvánNokonoko thanks for your answer